# Reuse helper objects or recreate them on usage?

Tags: java

I would like to get some experienced advice about the handling of helper objects. Consider the following situation where we want to build a connector to a third party system. The connector shall translate business objects/entities of our domain into entities of that system and transfer them via HTTP:

```java
abstract class BaseController {
    protected final HttpClient httpClient;
    // four more members like base URI and request timeout

    protected final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public BaseController(HttpClient httpClient /*and the other four members*/) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        // assigning the other members
    }

    protected HttpResponse<String> sendRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest, String restPath) {
        // send the request, handle exceptions and return the response
    }

    protected <T> T deserializeJson(String json, Class<T> type) {
        // call this.gson.fromJson(json, type), handle the JsonSyntaxException and return the result
    }
}

class EntityAController extends BaseController {
    public EntityAController(/* members of BaseController */) {
        super(/* the five parameters */);
    }

    void createEntityA(EntityA entity) {
        // translate entity into a corresponding entity of another system
        // pack this external entity into an HttpRequest
        this.sendRequest(httpRequest, "/externalEntity1");
    }
}

class EntityBController extends BaseController {
    public EntityBController(/* members of BaseController */) {
        super(/* the five parameters */);
    }

    void createEntityB(EntityB entity) {
        // translate entity into a corresponding entity of another system
        // pack this external entity into an HttpRequest
        this.sendRequest(httpRequest, "/externalEntity2");

        for (EntityBPart part : entity.parts()) {
            // translate the parts
            this.sendRequest(httpRequest, "/externalEntity2/part");
        }
    }
}

class Connector {
    protected final EntityAController entityAController;
    protected final EntityBController entityBController;

    public Connector(Map<String, String> options) {
        // create HttpClient and the four other members of BaseController out of the options

        this.entityAController = new EntityAController(httpClient/* and the rest */);
        this.entityBController = new EntityBController(httpClient/* and the rest */);
    }

    void createEntityA(EntityA entity) {
        this.entityAController.createEntityA(entity);
    }

    void createEntityB(EntityB entity) {
        this.entityBController.createEntityB(entity);
    }
}
```

The main question we are currently talking about is: is it legit to keep the instances of `Gson`, `EntityAController` and `EntityBController` in memory or not?

One party states that the multiple storage of stateless objects is more expensive for the JVM and the garbage collection than creating new instances at short term, which can be released directly after their calls. It would also make the code harder to read and maintain, because you always have to think about why the object is stored and reused.

The other party states that the above code is perfectly valid, since it saves object creation time. Especially in the case of EntityB which requires multiple requests, and creating a new Gson object for each request would be a waste of CPU. Memory management is not an issue since the JVM and the GC are made to handle objects. Keeping them is an equal use case to create/use/toss. And Spring (which is used to build some web services) does pretty much the same with its `@Autowired` members and `@Repository`s, `@Service`s et cetera.
And readability is not affected since this is simple OOP stuff. Every developer should be able to understand the code.

What do you think? Is one or the other considered best practice or bad practice? Are both approaches equal/valid? Does it depend on the invocation frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One party states that the multiple storage of stateless objects is
> more expensive for the JVM and the garbage collection than creating
> new instances at short term, which can be released directly after
> their calls. It would also make the code harder to read and maintain,
> because you always have to think about why the object is stored and
> reused.

While the JVM can efficiently handle short lived objects, that doesn't mean it inefficiently handles long lived objects, so the argument is wrong. It's not hard to read and maintain code when you know that an object is reused because it **can** be reused, even if the reuse doesn't provide any major advantage.

> The other party states that the above code is perfectly valid, since
> it saves object creation time. Especially in the case of EntityB which
> requires multiple requests, and creating a new Gson object for each
> request would be a waste of CPU.

Object creation isn't expensive in most cases either, so while that's a better argument than the other team, it's not that relevant to performance. Creating a DB `Connection` is expensive. Creating a `GSON` object is not expensive.

However, a `GSON` object is stateless and thread-safe, so there's no *need* for more than one instance (unless you need different configurations) to be shared by all your classes. You could change it to

```
protected final static Gson gson = new Gson();
```

to share the instance with all your controllers.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with long lived objects. Objects that live the lifetime of the program give you a nice fixed memory foot print. So long as that footprint isn't excessive it makes memory leaks easier to spot.

Ephemeral objects that get created over and over create the danger that they accumulate and grow without bound. Yes even in Java. Just hold a reference to them somewhere and the garbage collector wont free them. Even as you remake them again.

This isn't to say that ephemeral objects are always a bad idea. But since they are risky it's wise to limit their use to where that ephemeral nature is needed. For example Time Stamps are classic ephemeral objects. You can't create them at start up for a good reason. But please don't try to make everything an ephemeral object. Give `main()` something to do.